# Issue with jQuery event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Game-wrapper and game-wrapper2 divs have circular progress bar. I want to show first div, then play video, then show another div, and finally, play a second video.

I made this jQuery code, but it doesn't work.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      "use strict";
      
    var movie = jQuery('#gameVideo');
    var movie2 = jQuery('#gameVideo2');
      
     jQuery(".first-widget").click(function() {
      jQuery(".first-screen").hide();
      jQuery(".game").show();
      jQuery(".game-wrapper").show();
      movie[0].play();
      jQuery("#gameVideo").on("play", function () {
       jQuery(".game-wrapper").hide();
      });
      jQuery("#gameVideo").on("ended", function() {
       jQuery(".game-wrapper2").show();
      });
      movie2[0].play();
      jQuery("#gameVideo2").on("play", function () {
       jQuery(".game-wrapper2").hide();
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loading-div-right">
  <div class="first-screen"><img src="images/first-screen-animation.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="game">
    <img src="images/game-border.png" alt="">
    <div class="game-wrapper">
      <div class="left"></div>
      <div class="right"></div>
      <div class="mask"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <video width="300px" height="300px;" id="gameVideo" src="videos/lake.mp4"/>
    </div>
    <div class="game-wrapper2">
      <div class="left"></div>
      <div class="right"></div>
      <div class="mask"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <video width="300px" height="300px;" id="gameVideo2" src="videos/lake.mp4"/>
    </div>
  </div>          
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting your on("play") listeners before the click() ?

Comment: try to add your full code (include style)

Comment: My css is to long :(!

Comment: Event listeners are async, your `on('play')`/`on('ended')` calls do not wait and then continue on to `movie2[0].play();`. If you want your second video to play when the first ends you need to put `movie2[0].play();` in the `ended` callback

Comment: Use this `$('#videoId').get(0).play()`. See if it works.

Comment: @AakashThakur, `movie[0]` is the same as doing `$('#videoId').get(0)` both get the underlying DOM object

Comment: I don't now how, when i execute this code, it only load game-wrapper 2.

Comment: @AakashThakur, same thing doesn't work! Only shows game-wrapper2.

Comment: Where is your first-widget in the code...I dont see any element with first-widget class

Comment: <div class="loading-div-left">
<ul>
<li class="first-widget">></li>                                                                        <li class="second-widget"></li>
                <li class="third-widget"></li>
                <li class="fourth-widget"></li>
            </ul>
</div>

Comment: @Geeky It is beside floating-div-right.

Comment: Can you update the markup

Comment: @Geeky This is my first question on stackoverflow. I think that other part of code isn't important. I only need button for execute this jQuery action. Please can someone tell me what is wrong with my jQuery code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It helps to **create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example** to help other users diagnose and troubleshoot your issue. If your "CSS is too long", it means that you have not sufficiently reduced your issue to help even yourself at seeing the source of the problem. By processing the code, you not only help yourself at understanding it better, but also show the community that you have indeed invested some kind of effort. We can't help users that do not help themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Lets see your actions flow :

1. Show first div
2. Play video 1
3. Show another div
4. Play video 2

Lets see it now in details with events

1. Show first div & Start playing video 1
2. On Video 1 end --> Show another div & Start playing video 2
3. On Video 2 end --> Do something else

So you need 1 "OnEnded" event on each video

Now in the code for these steps based on your code:

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
// Define Video A
var movie = jQuery('#gameVideo');
// Define Video B
var movie2 = jQuery('#gameVideo2');

// My timer
var timer = null;

// If someone press this button,
// I will "Show first div" & "Play video 1"
jQuery(".first-widget").click(function() {

    // Reset all
    clearTimeout(timer);
    movie.stop();
    movie2.stop();
    movie.currentTime = 0;
    movie2.currentTime = 0;

    // Show first div
    // Or what ever you need to be visible
    jQuery(".first-screen").hide();
    jQuery(".game").show();
    jQuery(".game-wrapper").show();
    // Reset the other wrapper
    jQuery(".game-wrapper2").hide();

    // Wait 10 secs
    timer = setTimeout(function(){

        // Play video 1
        movie.show();
        movie[0].play();
        movie.show();
        jQuery(".game-wrapper").hide();

    }, 10*1000);

});

// Define Video A event listeners
// On the end of video A
movie.on("ended", function() {

    // Show another div
    movie.hide();
    jQuery(".game-wrapper2").show();
    jQuery(".game-wrapper").hide();

    // Wait 10 secs
    timer = setTimeout(function(){

        // Start playing video 2
        movie2.show();
        movie2[0].play();
        jQuery(".game-wrapper2").hide();

    }, 10*1000);

});

// Define Video B event listeners
// On the end of video B
movie2.on("ended", function () {

    // Do something else
    movie2.hide();
    jQuery(".game").hide();
    jQuery(".first-screen").show();

});
```

});

Some mistakes on your code:

1. you play both video the same time

   ```
    movie[0].play();
    ... // The commands here do not pause the code execution
    movie2[0].play();
   ```
2. you call an action and after that you define the event for this action

   ```
    movie[0].play(); // Fire play event ... there is no handler
    movie.on("play", function () { // Oh... now there is a handler but the event passed...
        jQuery(".game-wrapper").hide();
    });
   ```

---

### Some more asked code

Make a function to reset all elements... all elements from all widgets.

```
var resetAll = function(){
    // Clear timer
    clearTimeout(timer);

    // Stop all videos
    movie1.stop();
    movie2.stop();
    movie3.stop();
    ...

    // Reset all videos
    movie1.currentTime = 0;
    movie2.currentTime = 0;
    movie3.currentTime = 0;
    ...

    // Hide all video wrappers elements
    // first-widget
    jQuery(".first-screen").hide();
    jQuery(".game").hide();
    jQuery(".game-wrapper").hide();
    jQuery(".game-wrapper2").hide();
    // second-widget
    jQuery(".first-screen").hide();
    jQuery(".music").hide();
    jQuery(".music-wrapper").hide();
    jQuery(".music-wrapper2").hide();
    // third-widget
    ...

}
```

then call it at the begining of the click on a widget.

```
jQuery(".first-widget").click(function() {

    // Reset all
    resetAll();

    ...

});

jQuery(".second-widget").click(function() {

    // Reset all
    resetAll();

    ...

});

...
```

Comment: The code is based on your code, which in some case does not make sense :P , let me guess what you want to do...

Comment: Yes it's my code, but i think it is wrong. Div game-wrapper and game-wrapper2 have circular progress bar with animation. They last about 10 seconds each. I want, when i click on button, start that animation, after animation is finished, start playing first video. When video stops, show second div with another animation of 10 seconds. After animation stops, it start playing video 2.

Comment: Check it now, I added 10 sec delay, but I don't know that you want to do after the end of the second video.

Comment: It only shows first animation, first div, than nothing happens, and then it shows div("first-widget"). After the end of the second video i want to show first image div again. It is starting point.

Comment: It is now fixed. Also corect your html code, `<video width="300" height="300"/>` html `width` and `height` are numbers, not css, so no `px`.

Comment: You are the best. Thank you very much. I don't what tou say. You help me a lot.

Comment: I have problem, now i have four clicks and four different proces. When i click on different div, it doesn't stop to execute code from previous div. How can i stop that?

Comment: I edited the code, you need to save the timeouts on a timer, and on click clear the timers. Also you need to reset the videos, so you stop them, and set them to time 0.

Comment: Your html is wrong not the javascript, for example, you try to show `#music-wrapper` but there is no element with this id... Also timer should be 1 variable not timer1, timer2 ..., only 1 timer valible and all use it.
You should try to understand the code and not just copy paste it.

Comment: Sorry but i don't find any #music-wrapper in my code. Wirth one var timer, when i click, it shows one div, but when i click on another, doesn't hide anything.

Comment: You are right, my bad, its `.music-wrapper` no `#music-wrapper` but there is no element with `music-wrapper` class in your html.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't update my html. Try now to check my code.

Comment: Now, i need to change order of playing. I need to simultaneously show game wrapper and game wrapper2, and after finished animation, need to play movie. I customize code, but it doesn't want to reset movie playing, after i click on another section.

Comment: https://codepen.io/jovicabojic/pen/xEydQQ Here is the code. Try to understand, i'm new to javascript.